# How to find duplicates within each row in R

Tags: r, duplicates

How do you find if there are duplicates **within a row** using R?

The attached file is an example of a supervisor reporting hierarchy. There should be no repeat numbers within a row, as each person cannot report back to someone down the hierarchy.

In the example image, row 2 has two 6's, row 3 has two 10's, so I want to create a 'duplicate' column indicating "Y" for duplicates. Any other suggestions are welcome.

[image]

is a 'for loop (for i in 1:nrow)' or 'apply' a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the column using `ifelse()`

```
data$duplicate <- ifelse(apply(data, 1, function(row) any(duplicated(row))), "Y", "N")
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a simple solution! Why can't we use this instead?                    apply(test, 1, function(row) ifelse(any(duplicated(row)), "Y", "N"))

Comment: That's even better!

Answer (score 1):

We can check with `duplicated` by looping over the rows, get a logical vector as output and change it "N", "Y" after converting to binary

```
df1$duplicate <- c("N", "Y")[1+ (
               apply(df1, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(x))))]
df1$duplicate
#[1] "N" "Y" "Y" "Y"
```

---

Or it can be more compact

```
df1$duplicate <- c("N", "Y")[1+(apply(df1, 1, anyDuplicated)>0)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sup1 = c(1, 5, 9, 13), Sup2 = c(2, 6, 10, 14),
    Sup3 = c(3, 6, 11, 15), Sup4 = c(4, 8, 10, 16), Sup5 = c(20, 22, 11, 13))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
df$dup <- ifelse(rowSums(do.call(rbind,Map(duplicated,data.frame(t(df)))))>0,"Y","N")
```

such that

```
> df
  sup1 sup2 sup3 sup4 sup5 dup
1    1    2    3    4   20   N
2    5    6    6    8   22   Y
3    9   10   11   10   11   Y
4   13   14   15   16   13   Y
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(sup1 = c(1,5,9,13),
                 sup2 = c(2,6,10,14),
                 sup3 = c(3,6,11,15),
                 sup4 = c(4,8,10,16),
                 sup5 = c(20,22,11,13))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table` to count the number of occurrences in each row and return `"Y"` if any value is repeated.

```
df$duplicate <- c("N", "Y")[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(table(x) > 1)) + 1]
df

#  Sup1 Sup2 Sup3 Sup4 Sup5 duplicate
#1    1    2    3    4   20         N
#2    5    6    6    8   22         Y
#3    9   10   11   10   11         Y
#4   13   14   15   16   13         Y
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! What does the '+1' do?

Comment: @AmandaLow The output from `apply` is a logical vector (`TRUE`/`FALSE`). We change it to 2 and 1 respectively by using `+1` which is then used to subset `"N"` and `"Y"`.